# When the sum of two generators of a simple field extension is also a generator?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic zero, and let $a$ be algebraic over $F$, so $K=F(a)$ is a finite separable field extension.
Assume that $b$ is also a generator for $K$ over $F$, namely $K=F(b)$.
Also assume that $a+b \notin F$.
(Notice that the degree of the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $F$ equals
the degree of the minimal polynomial of $b$ over $F$).

**Is it possible to tell when $a+b$ is also a generator for $K$ over $F$?**
For example, if $[K:F]$ is a prime number, then $F(a+b)=K$.

See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862300/why-ab-is-a-generator-of-fa-b-over-f-where-f-is-a-field-of-character#comment3813983_1862300) which reminds that for all but finitely many $F \ni \lambda$'s, $F(a+\lambda b)=F(a)$ (in our case $F(a)=F(b)=F(a,b)$); however, it seems that there is no way to tell if $\lambda=1$ will work unless additional details are given.

Comment: The first answer in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26832/degree-of-sum-of-algebraic-numbers?noredirect=1&lq=1 is perhaps relevant here, although it does not answer my question (which probably does not have a general answer as I wish).