# Why $a+b$ is a generator of $F(a,b)$ over $F$, where $F$ is a field of characteristic zero.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic zero. Assume that $a$ and $b$ are algebraic over $F$.
The primitive element theorem says that there exists $w \in F(a,b)$ 
such that $F(a,b)=F(w)$; such $w$ is called a primitive element for the extension.
A standard proof shows that $a+\lambda b$ is a primitive element for the extension for all but finitely many $F \ni \lambda$'s.

The [exercise](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~kbrown/6310/primitive.pdf) in this note says that $\lambda=1$ yields a primitive element,
namely, $F(a,b)=F(a+b)$. 
I am not sure I know how to solve that exercise. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: The note only seems to claim that for a specific case, $\lambda=1$ works. I doubt that is true in general but don't have a counterexample off the top of my head.

Comment: For a counterexample, consider $a=\sqrt{2}$ and $b=1-\sqrt{2}$ and $F=\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Both of you are right, of course...Thanks for the nice and easy counterexample.